# AES шифрование/расшифрование 128 бит

Tags: криптография

Здравствуйте!

Возможно ли зашифровать текст длинною больше чем 16 символов в AES 128? Т.к. в AES 128 используется матрица состояния (State) размером 4x4. В примере http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/cs381-05/blockciphers/rijndael_ingles2004.swf ничего не было сказано в отношении того, как они вычислили cipher key и как расшифровать текст после того, как пройдет последний цикл key schedule, также не пояснено, что мы вообще шифруем. Зачем такие статьи писать, если не указано, как происходит обратная дешифровка.
Можете ли Вы порекомендовать статьи, в которых описана каждая стадия шифрования/расшифрования сначала и до конца на каком-нибудь конкретном примере (допустим, мы хотим зашифровать текст "сообщение1для12", и что нужно будет делать после key schedule, чтобы получить обратно исходный текст). В большинстве статьей касательно AES вообще не написано, как проводить обратный процесс дешифровки после шифрования, и не показано, какой текст мы изначально шифруем, также не написано, как сгенерировать cipher key и какую роль он играет при расшифровании. Описаны только процедуры подсчета MixColumns, ShiftRows, XOR, но опять же нету ни одной статьи для шифровки/дешифровки какого-нибудь текста.
Хотелось бы пример не реализации AES, а как вручную делать все эти операции от и до на бумаге.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: > Зачем такие статьи писать, если не указана как происходит обратная дешифровка.

Двойной xor всегда даст изначальное значение; другими словами, при симметричном шифровании надо восстановить тот же самый ключ (не оригинальные 128-192-256 бит, а длинную портянку, которой xor'ился plaintext) и заxor'ить им ciphertext. Конкретный алгоритм зависит от реализации (ECB, CBC, IGE и пр.), но в целом при шифровании и дешифровании львиная (если не вся, как с ЕСВ) часть действий абсолютно одинакова.

Comment: Спасибо, а где можно посмотреть пример шифровки/расшифровки на каком нибудь конкретном тексте, где будут описаны эти шаги. Повторюсь что их нигде нету, на habrahabr тоже нету таких примеров, только нотации как делать MixColumn, ShiftRows. Даже не описали что такое cipher key, plain text

Comment: @Rrace8, я на самом деле сталкивался только с необходимостью реализовать IGE, что всё равно делал через стороннюю либу, но попадался вот такой вот документ, в котором есть примеры для IGE: http://www.links.org/files/openssl-ige.pdf

С криптографией всегда такие проблемы, потому что она очень муторная. Вам нужно где-нибудь раздобыть саму спеку AES и делать все по ней (если вы действительно хотите сделать собственную реализацию), примеры можно генерировать с помощью openssl и сравнивать результаты. Но как сами понимаете, дебаг неправильно зашифрованного текста - это адище.

Comment: Честно сказать про ECB, CBC, IGE не слышал, сперва хотелось бы полностью понять, как работает самый простой 128 битный AES. Я сперва думал, что на стадии MixColumns можно достать значения из state, далее сконвертировать их из hex в bin, записать получившиеся значения в String, для того чтобы проверить, если первая цифра в bin равна 1, то тогда мы сдвигаем bin влево, затем из String обратно конвертируем в bin и умножаем на 02,03,01. Вроде бы это правильно. Но опять же нигде нету примера, чтобы можно было сверяться.

Comment: @Rrace8, это для себя что-то на коленке или нечто серьезное?

--

Если серьезное, то уже давно для подобной деятельности надо получать соответствующие сертификаты.

Если для себя -- то не заморачивайтесь, заксорьте текст результатами rand(), а srand() в начале сделайте от какого-нибудь хэша пароля.

Comment: Для себя. И у меня даже сложилось впечатление,что нигде нету примера шифровки/дешифровки "на пальцах" (не код), т.к. реализация разрешена крупным компаниям, и Вы это мнение подтвердили. А остальные он-лайн сервисы AES используют готовые библиотеки, что нечестно.

Comment: @Rrace8, я так понимаю, @avp имел в виду не разрешения на работу в данной области, а сертификаты, подтверждающие наличие знаний по вопросу. Насколько понимаю, свободная разработка криптографического ПО если и запрещена, то только у нас.

Comment: @Etki, разработка не запрещена (у нас тоже). 

Запрещено **использование** официально несертефицированного софта. 

Именно этот запрет я и имел в виду, а не получение каких-то (мистических) сертификатов на наличие знаний.

Comment: Нашел подробный пример, но опять же там нету процесса дешифровки, и тем более необычно происходит процедура ShiftRows, то есть сдвиг всегда идет только на 1 элемент вверх, это совсем не так, как описано в остальных примерах. http://www.kavaliro.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/AES.pdf В этом примере http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/cs381-05/blockciphers/rijndael_ingles2004.swf на 4 слайде, где идет процедура AddRoundKey, не описано, как на 1 цикле появилась таблица RoundKey и как ее заполнить еще при 1 цикле. Пробовал складывать (XOR) State с Before Subbytes State, но это совсем не эти значения.

Comment: @Rrace8, а [вот эти исходники](https://polarssl.org/aes-source-code) не то, что Вы ищете?

Comment: @Rrace8

Дико извиняюсь, но почему бы для начала не почитать теорию. Хотя бы чуть-чуть. Например, про то, что такое симметричный алгоритм.